# How can I get illustrator to automatically clip the artboard to the vectorized objects size?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, vector, cs6, svg

I just exported a shape from photoshop as a path and then filled it in illustrator. I now want to save the shape as an svg, or eps but I don't want to save all the excess whitespace around the object. I want it to be cropped to the dimensions of the object and not the artboard. How can I do this in Adobe Illustrator cs6?

Answer (score 44):

You can set the artboard to match the outer dimensions of any object by selecting the object and choosing `Object > Artboards > Fit to Selected Art` from the menu.

Comment: My quickest way is to group everything I want to have in the Artboard, select the Artboard tool (shift+o) and doubleclick the group ...

Comment: Is there a way to do this with a small margin?

Comment: but what if I have shadow? it clips shadow

Answer (score 4):

I am currently using CC, so I appologize if this option does not exist in CS6

When you open the "Save for Web" dialog, there is a check box that reads "Clip to Artboard". Un-tick that.

[image]

This will shape the final image to the size of the WHOLE art in the file, ignoring the artboards.

Comment: Yes, that is a great tip for for JPEG or PNG, but Save for Web does not have the option to save as SVG or EPS as the user requested.

Answer (score 4):

Select the artboard tool, delete the current artboard, then click on your object. Illustrator should create a new artboard at the exact dimensions of the object.

Answer (score 1):

A nice shortcut, if  Illustrator & the computer you're using aren't sluggish with the file you've got open, is to just hit the keystroke to "Save for Web".

If you've previously checked the "Clip to Artboard" box, which cockypup mentioned, it stays checked. So you'll get a preview that's clipped to artboard. Whack Esc to dismiss it.

Answer (score 1):

On Adobe Illustrator CS6:

- Step1 > Double click on artboard tool.(Art board options window will
  appear)
- Step2 > click on 'preset' combo box.
- Step3 > Select 'Fit to Artwork Bounds' and click on 'ok'button.

And you are done!:)

Comment: This also works for CS4 just fine.

Answer (score 0):

**1.Select your object using the selection tool**
[image: selct the cobject]

**2.Select Object on the top toolbar then select Artboards then fit to selected art**
[image: object-> artboards- fit to selected art]

Answer (score -4):

Save the image as a .png file. make sure to check transparency.

Comment: This does not answer the question. The Asker states they want to save a .svg, not .png.

Comment: Hi Luke, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!